# JTable from TableModel - add Buttons to each row

Tags: java, jtable, tablemodel

I have a school project where I need to create a gui for a database. The database contains 3 tables:

1. a table for pizzas
2. a table for toppings
3. And a table, which contains the foreign keys for the pizzas and toppings. Basically this table declares, what toppings does a pizza have.

I can display now the pizza table in a `JTable` through a custom `TableModel` (the table model communicates with the database).

But now I would like to add two columns for the table. These columns would contain two buttons in each row, one for deleting the actual row, one for opening a dialog, which enables to edit the current pizza (add toppings, change attributes, etc.).

How can I add these columns, if I "feed" the JTable from a custom table model? Do I need to modify the table model, or the `JTable`?

Comment: Take a look at `TableCellRenderer` and `TableCellEditor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `JButton` (with correct workaround for `TableCellRenderer` and `TableCellEditor`) in the `JTable`'s cell is one hardiest jobs in the `Swing`,

1) @camickrs [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/)

2) add [JPanel with JComponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726701/714968) to the `JTable`'s column